# Windows Azure deployed webrole is not accessible

Tags: azure-web-roles

I have deployed the web application to the Windows Azure through Visual Studio 2010 and the Windows Azure SDK version is 1.8.
The deployment is done in production, the status is showing as Running, but i cannot access the Site URL. When i try to access the Site URL the browser give the error "Page not found". 
Since there is no clue on the error, please someone give the proper way to know the reason why the webrole is not accessible

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when I first started on azure. 
Here's how to do it;
Go to the azure panel,

- click on your VM
- click enpoints
- click ADD
- check the ADD A STAND-ALONE ENDPOINT (button)
- click next
- Enter the following details:
  Name: HTTP, Protocol: TCP, Public port: 80, and private port:80
- Complete and wait a few minutes for activation(mine took like 40seconds)

your site url will now be accesible from any browser.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

Configure your web.config to show stacktrace. That will give you a clue.

If you absolutely cant have any visitors see the stacktrace change it to remoteonly and browse the site from witin the web service like this: http://geekswithblogs.net/MagnusKarlsson/archive/2012/12/03/connect-to-running-web-role-from-remote-desktop-connection-and.aspx

Or set it to Off, deploy and browse. Thats what I do when I have a testsite thats not in production mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="url"
              mode="On|Off|RemoteOnly">
   <error statusCode="statuscode"
          redirect="url"/>
</customErrors>
```